# D3 - migrate multi column chart code from v3 to v7

Tags: d3.js

I have multi column chart in D3 v3 and I have to port this code to new D3 v7. In old version column generated, in new i have column groups but not generate column in groups. What I doing wrong?

```
// serries
        let series = this.seriesContainer.selectAll('.series')
            .data(this.data.series);

        series.enter()
            .append('g')
            .classed('series', true)
            .attr('fill', (s, i) => colorTable[i])
            .attr('transform', (s, i) => this.createTranslateProperty((i * (categoryScale.bandwidth() / this.data.series.length))));
        series.exit().remove();

// columns
        let dataSelector = (s: ColumnChartDataSeriesModelI) => s.values

        let columns = series.selectAll('.columnChartColumn').data(dataSelector);
        columns.enter()
            .append('rect')
            .classed('columnChartColumn', true);

        columns.attr("rx", 5)
            .attr("font-size", 10)
            .attr('width', (categoryScale.bandwidth() / this.data.series.length) - 2)
            .attr('height', 10)
            .attr('y', 10)
            .attr('x', (v, i) => categoryScale(this.data.categories[i]));

        columns.exit().remove();
```

```
// data model
export interface ColumnChartDataSeriesModelI {
    values: Array<number>
};
```

In effect in V7 I got HTML

```
...
<g class="columnChartSeriesContainer">
  <g class="series" fill="#0084F5" transform="translate(0,0)"></g>
  <g class="series" fill="#FA8F32" transform="translate(23,0)"></g>
</g>
...
```

when old V3 generate HTML

```
<g class="columnChartSeriesContainer">
   <g class="series" fill="#0084F5" transform="translate(0,0)">
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="270" y="0" x="1"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="210" y="60" x="63"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="150" y="120" x="125"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="150" y="120" x="187"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="240" y="30.000000000000014" x="249"></rect>
   </g>
   <g class="series" fill="#FA8F32" transform="translate(25,0)">
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="60" y="210" x="1"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="180" y="90.00000000000001" x="63"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="89.99999999999997" y="180.00000000000003" x="125"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="30" y="240" x="187"></rect>
      <rect class="columnChartColumn" rx="5" font-size="10" width="23" height="60" y="210" x="249"></rect>
   </g>
</g>
```

**Edit - solution:**

Aparently the returned object to variables **serries** and **columns** wasn't proper when I assign like this

```
let series = this.seriesContainer.selectAll('.series').data(this.data.series);
```

I solved this writing like this

```
        let series = this.seriesContainer.selectAll('.series').data(this.data.series)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .classed('series', true);

        series.attr('fill', (s, i) => colorTable[i])
            .attr('transform', (s, i) => this.createTranslateProperty((i * (categoryScale.bandwidth() / this.data.series.length))));
            
        series.exit().remove();

        let columns = series.selectAll('.columnChartColumn').data(dataSelector).enter()
            .append('rect')
            .classed('columnChartColumn', true);

        columns.attr("rx", 5)
            .attr('width', (categoryScale.bandwidth() / this.data.series.length) - 2)
            .attr('height', v => columnMaxSize - columnScale(v))
            .attr('y', v => columnScale(v))
            .attr('x', (v, i) => categoryScale(this.data.categories[i]));

        columns.exit().remove();
```

Comment: Maybe check where you define `categoryScale`.  In v3 you'd use something like `d3.scale.band`, in v7 it's `d3.scaleBand`

Comment: let categoryScale = d3.scaleBand().domain... - looks correct. Even if I set attributes values as constant values its same effect :/. For some reason 
columns.enter().append('rect') do not creating child elements... And data from "dataSelector" looks good to...

Comment: best way to migrate from V3 to V7 would be to go through release notes. here's a link : https://github.com/d3/d3/releases. It seems like a lot of work but definitely worth it